# How to use :params in React router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Having issues with the react-router picking up on a nested route. A param is passed to accommodate for any subsequent links to be conditionally rendered later in the child component passed into Route

```
import React from "react";

import { Route } from "react-router-dom";

import CollectionsOverview from "../../components/collections-overview/collections-overview";
import CollectionPage from "../collection/collection";

const ShopPage = ({ match }) => {
  return (
    <div className="shop-page">
      <Route exact path={`${match.path}`} component={CollectionsOverview} />
      <Route path={`${match.path}/:collectionId`} component={CollectionPage} />
    </div>
  );
};
export default ShopPage;
```

```
import React from "react";
import "./collection.styles.scss";

const CollectionPage = ({ match }) => {
  return (
    <div className="collection-page">
      <h2>COLLECTION PAGE: {match.params.collectionId}</h2>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CollectionPage;
```

Route 2 never renders its component on route manipulation

Answer (score 1):

You can use `useParams`. Please check this example:

```
import React from "react";
import {BrowserRouter as Router,Switch,Route,Link,useParams} from "react-router-dom";

export default function ParamsExample() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <h2>Accounts</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <Link to="/netflix">Netflix</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/zillow-group">Zillow Group</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/yahoo">Yahoo</Link>
          </li>
          <li>
            <Link to="/modus-create">Modus Create</Link>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/:id" children={<Child />} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

function Child() {
  let { id } = useParams();

  return (
    <div>
      <h3>ID: {id}</h3>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Source](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params)

Comment: Accessing params doesn't seem to be the problem as I am not even able to render the `CollectionPage`  component.It is not rendered when I change the path in the address bar to say `/shop/randomString`. match.path which evaluates to /shop/ should render CollectionsOverview and match.path/:randomString should render the  collectionPage component and them make randomString accessible as :params in the rendered component. This is the bahavior I'm trying to achieve

Comment: fixed! I realized that the component which was to switch between the 2 Routes was rendered with an {exact} bool in its parent Route,  so any time the route was changed the component wasn't even rendered in the first place to look at the URL and render the appropriate child Route.Taking out the exact bool fixed it.

Comment: great. Thank you